# jQuery - find all elements without someone between

Tags: jquery

For example we have such dom:

```
<div id="main" class=".container">
    any other elements
    <div>
       <span class="edit" />
    </div>
    <div class=".container">
         <div class="edit">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make query, to select only first edit

Something like $('#main .edit:not(.container between)')

Comment: Don't use class=".container", but class="container"

Comment: I think everyone misunderstood the question. The question is how to select all elements of class "edit", excluding the ones that were contained inside a div with class "container". In the example, that's indeed the first one, but being the first match is not the criteria here.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather confusing when the outer container is also of class "container".

This works:

```
$('#main .edit:not(#main .container .edit)')
```

If your outer div doesn't have the "container" class:

```
$('#main .edit:not(.container .edit)')
```

*(note: you shouldn't use class=".container", but class="container")*

Comment: I don't see why it would break if there is more than one layer of nesting. The selector ".container .edit" matches any "edit" class below a "container" class, no matter how deeply nested.